# Should @font-face declarations be done early in the css file or towards the end?

Tags: css, font-face

Is there a difference in performance (or otherwise) for when a `@font-face` is declared? Does calling it early in the css file have a positive/negative impact? Is this different if the font is coming from an external CDN like Google Fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of declaration doesn't really affect the performance provided that the font has been used only after declaration. I don't think there is any difference in using an external CDN. For further reference see [this](http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/).

Comment: Does that mean that using the font before the font-face declaration causes problems?

Comment: It might! as the browser will not be able to identify the font you are trying to display without a reference i.e. the url you provide with the declaration.

Comment: Originally, my font-face delcaration was at the end of the css file, but after moving it to the top before any usage, the font seems to pop in slightly faster, but I can't tell if that's an actual benefit, or just a placebo effect. Either way, I guess it will probably be better off at the top regardless for the sake of avoiding potential load issues.

Comment: You should try this out with different browsers to know more about how things change with different browsers.

Comment: I'll definitely test this further once I've completed my website. Testing with a large and complete css file will definitely show a more accurate result than a nearly empty file.

Comment: Sure. If you are satisfied with my part please accept the answer. That would be helpful